# CSS Scope and Multiple Classes

Tags: html, css, scope

I've ran into an issue where the parent scope is having an argument with its children.

What I was trying to accomplish is by setting the default color scheme for my page in the top level div (or body tag in my case). And have the ability to change the colors deeper down the DOM.

However when I use the following the inner DIV's are purple, and **not** red (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16t7g9cm/4/) for demo).

Now if I swap the classes around in the file it works (the order in which they reside in the file), however this is not a solution in my case as its also possible for a 'red page' with purple panels and the same problem would arise.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/16t7g9cm/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="purple">
    <div class="red panel"> .red.panel </div>
    <div class="red">
       <div class="panel"> .red .panel </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel"> .panel </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red .panel,
.panel.red {
    background-color: #cc3300;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.purple .panel,
.panel.purple {
    background-color: #990099;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Can anyone explain/ point me to what causes this behavior and any possible solutions.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same specificity however `purple` comes after `red` in the CSS and therefore is overriding it.

You can simply switch them around to solve the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/16t7g9cm/7/

```
.purple .panel,
.panel.purple {
    background-color: #990099;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.red .panel,
.panel.red {
    background-color: #cc3300;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

---

However if you can't reorder the classes you could make the *red* selectors would specific:

```
.purple .red .panel,
.purple .panel.red {
    background-color: #cc3300;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Your pre-edit answer was more in the direction I was looking - please revert :-)

As stated in the response of other answer and in the original post it's flexible. It should work both ways (red and purple can be swapped and then we would have the same situation).

Comment: @JennevanderMeer Updated answer

Comment: Although not ideal less generates a massive CSS file with the 7 colors cause I have to match each color vs each color.. However I don't see any other option so accepted (and using the 2nd method) it.

Comment: @JennevanderMeer Some of the parent selectors which Less supports might be of help, but I'm not 100% sure - http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature

Answer (score 0):

This is a specificity issue the closer you are to the DOM the more specific you are so if you just replace the position of your css statements:

```
.purple .panel,
.panel.purple {
    background-color: #990099;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.red .panel,
.panel.red {
    background-color: #cc3300;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

it would work :)
http://jsfiddle.net/16t7g9cm/6/

---

Another way if ordering is a bit hard is to make it more specific (its hacky but works):

```
.red.red .panel,
.panel.red.red {
    background-color: #cc3300;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.purple .panel,
.panel.purple {
    background-color: #990099;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

as you see instead of .red I have .red.red which is the same thing but give you more specificity
http://jsfiddle.net/16t7g9cm/8/

Comment: As stated in my post it will work in this specific example, but doesn't get rid of the problem as its also possible to swap them around on my website. Basically every area has a unique recognizable color - and elements from another area should be in their associated color on any page)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code and you code will work fine

```css
.red .panel,
.panel.red {
    background-color: #cc3300 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

your parent styles are applied to the child element, hence current specified code will override the existing parent theme when conditions are met.

Comment: I don't believe this is a valid use of `!important` https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Indeed this won't help, as both purple and red would be important and cancel each other out being left with the same thing - it could work if the root class was always purple, but in my case its not.

Comment: Yes you're right. Based on the requirement this won't work. Curt's answer seems to be the best solution.